# Geofence didEnterRegion and didExitRegion are not called on Testflight beta app. What am I missing?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, testflight, fastlane

Updating existing and working native wrapper app to Swift 4, Xcode 9.2, and testing with iPhone 6s iOS 11.2.6 (from Swift 3, Xcode 7.2, iOS 9.2).

Geofence delegate (AppDelegate) fires/executes `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` when I simulate location on local environment through Xcode using .gpx files.  When I deploy using fastlane to Testflight beta app the delegates do not fire when crossing geofence.  I've added alerts to verify that the delegates are not being called.  Per other stackoverflow questions I've made sure to include `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in addition to `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key that's already in the `Info.plist` file.

I've turned on Background Capabilities for `Location Updates` and `Remote Notifications` I see them on the `Info.plist` file.  I can see in my database that a geotracking record was created with a geotoken when I grant/authorize location permissions (Authorized Always).

I'm using `CLCircularRegion` with a radius of 100 meters.  I've `region.notifyOnEntry = true` and `region.notifyOnExit = true`.

I'm deducing that the issue is that I'm missing something when I deploy using Fastlane (although I'm not getting any errors) or that I'm missing some configuration/setting.  Any ideas?  How can I debug this?  Is there a log in Testflight for my app?  What other information can I provide to help figure out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This hurts.  Apparently there is a little bit of precision rounding when we save latitude and longitude (or I was asleep at the wheel that day).  When I mapped the saved latitude and longitude I realized that it's nowhere near the needed fence.  I re-adjusted my latitude and longitude and everything works fine again.  Always check the input data for accuracy.  Hopefully this helps somebody else save time.

Comment: Other then accuracy u fixed anything?Please update answer that what are the permissions to be added in it.